# What is the vapour pressure of carbon at room temperature?

Tags: phase-transition, evaporation

The vapour pressure of carbon at 3642°C is one atmosphere (this is the sublimation temperature [given in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon)).

At lower temperatures, the vapour pressure will be less, but of course it will never be exactly zero.

However, I have not been able to find a reference which gives an actual or estimated value for the vapour pressure at (let's say) 20°C. The consensus seems "too low to be interesting", which leaves it lazily open as to whether it is $10^{-6}$ torr or $10^{-20}$ torr or whatever.

Can anyone help, or point to a suitable reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can estimate it using the [Clausius-Clapeyron relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation#Chemistry_and_chemical_engineering), which can be rewritten for the vapor pressure as
$$ p_v = p_0 \exp\left(-\frac{E_v}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T_0}\right)\right),$$
where $R=8.314~\mathrm{JK^{-1}mol^{-1}}$ is the universal gas constant, $p_0$ is the vapor pressure at a given temperature $T_0$, and $E_v$ is the heat of vaporization (in J/mol). With carbon, take $p_0=1~\mathrm{bar}$ and $T_0=3915$ K, $E_v=117$ kJ/mol. Then at room temperature (293 K), you'd expect $p_v=$ 5e-20 bar = 5e-17 hPa.

Typically, this expression is not exact due to subtle temperature dependences of the entropy, but it should be reasonably close.

Answer (score 0):

Ev= 716.982 Kj/mole not 117 Kj/mole for graphite.  Also R= 8.31446261815324 JK-1mol-1 according to NIST most recent constants.  This gives 8.6 E-117 atm. or 8.7 E-117 bar.  Because carbon vapor is mostly monatomic at temperatures below 1000 K and has considerable polymerization above 1500 K and the heat of vaporization of carbon does vary with temperature according to the thermodynamic functions, the actual pressure is about 3.6 E-113 pascals at 298.15 K which is virtually zero.  The JANAF 4th Edition tables give 2.5 E-118 bar at 298.15 K with C1 as the dominate species and extremely small amounts of C2,C3,C4,C5 polymers or higher at this 298.15 K temperature.  The JANAF tables appear to be a factor of approximately 1.4 too low in vapor pressure assuming the boiling point of 3915 is correct in Wikipedia.  Base on past experiments on carbon lamps, the boiling point of 3642 C (3915 K) given in Wikipedia is sublimation accurate and that the JANAF tables are too low by about a factor of 1.4 even when taking the summation of all polymer species into account.  Also the JANAF tables do not take in account the solid/liquid transition at approximately 4850 K to 4900 K at a vapor pressure of 107 atm. or 108 bar.  Graphite vapor is essentially monatomic below 1000 K and Polymers in carbon vapor become very important above 1200 K.